# ¿Por qué especificar el tipo de retorno void en PHP7?

Tags: php

LLevo unos días en un nuevo equipo. Revisando mi código me han indicado que no es necesario poner **void** como tipo de retorno de un método PHP... y me lo borraron...

¿Para que añadieron el tipo de retorno ***void*** al lenguaje PHP? ¿cuál es su función?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El tipo de retorno **void** se incorporó en PHP 7.1.

**Al indicar que un método o función tiene un tipo de retorno *void*, indicamos que no retorna nada**, siendo válidos, por ejemplo:

```
function noReturn() : void
{
   // code
}

function noReturn2() : void
{
   // code
   return ;
}
```

**Indicar el tipo de retorno *void* mejora la legibilidad del código**. Podemos ver el método o función y, sin tener que entrar en su cuerpo, saber que no tiene sentencias return devolviendo algún tipo de contenido.

> Editado.

Si nuestro editor de código nos permite "plegar código", para echar un vistazo rápido, apreciaremos rápidamente la **mejora en cuanto a legibilidad que nos da especificar tipos de retorno**, por ejemplo, podríamos tener:

```
class Xxx
{
    function getName() : string
    {...}

    function noReturn() : void
    {...}

    function noReturn2() : void
    {...}
}
```

donde queda claro que **sin tener que entrar a ver la implementación de los métodos, ni usar comentarios, sabemos si los métodos devuelven o no algo, y el tipo en caso afirmativo.**

**Fuentes consultadas:**

[php.net - Seudotipos y variables usadas](http://php.net/manual/es/language.pseudo-types.php)
[php.net - Nuevas características](http://php.net/manual/es/migration71.new-features.php)
[php.net - Devolver valores](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.returning-values.php)
[Actualizate a PHP7](https://www.kroatoan.es/articulos/actualizate-a-php-7-mejoras-operadores-y-sintaxis/)

Comment: Buena pregunta, para ayudarnos a descubrir cosas de PHP 7. Pero, dado que es una autorespuesta, se agradece que pongas alguna fuente a la que poder referirnos. Yo te creo, pero es mejor si nos indicas la fuente. Gracias.

Comment: @A. Cedano, fuentes añadidas. Curiosamente empecé a ver la mejora de legibilidad de usar este tipo, trabajando con *TypeScript* que en cuanto a tipos de retorno tiene la misma sintaxis que PHP7.

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo a la documentación de PHP en la versión 7.1 se ha introducido dicha característica.

**EJEMPLO 1**

```
function metodo(): void
{
    return "Hola";
}

echo metodo();
```

Mostrará este error

> **Fatal error**:  A void function must not return a value in
>   **[...][...]** on line **6**

Por que como su nombre lo indica un método `void` esta pensando para no retornar valores

Referencia http://php.net/manual/es/migration71.new-features.php

Dado que un método de tipo `void` no puede retornar un valor entonces este ejemplo podría dar un mejor ejemplo de su uso

```
$value;
function metodo($value): void
{
    if($value > 1000){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        echo 2;
    }
}

echo metodo(200);
```